# How to perform Email type verification during parsing(OpenCSV, spring boot)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, opencsv

I am using opencsv to read from a csv file in Spring boot.
Like usual, I have used @csvbindbyname annotation to bind every column(of csv) to the required entity member.
But say if I have a string field, which must have the structure of an Email, is there an annotation present to parse correctly and check if it follows a correct email pattern??

Example

```
@Email
@CsvBindByName(required = true)
private String email;
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: there is no pre-built feature to do that, you need to implement your own validation based on your use case.

Comment: [Hibernate Validator](https://hibernate.org/validator/) has an [@Email annotation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/api/index.html?org/hibernate/validator/constraints/Email.html). (This is completely separate from OpenCSV.)